# XML get value of tag without childrens value

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I'm trying to get the value of the `<data>` tag below (This is a test value). I read it with XElement in a Windows Form Application. But if I use `element.Value` I get a string with all the values of the children as well. The final XML file that needs to be read is a generated XML file. So the solution needs to be dynamic. No fixed names.

The result of `element.Value` is: `This is a test value   Jack22New YorkGuido21HollywoodMichael20BostonMy-Computer-1`

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data name="data_resource" howabout="no">
    This is a test value
    <persons>
        <person>
            <name>Jack</name>
            <age>22</age>
            <pob>New York</pob>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>Guido</name>
            <age>21</age>
            <pob>Hollywood</pob>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name surname="Bats">Michael</name>
            <age>20</age>
            <pob>Boston</pob>
        </person>
    </persons>
    <computers>
        <computer>
            <name>My-Computer-1</name>
            <test>
                <test2>
                    <test3>
                        <test4 testAttr="This is an attribute" y="68" x="132">
                            Hatseflatsen!
                        </test4>
                    </test3>
                </test2>
            </test>
        </computer>
    </computers>
</data>
```

Does anyone has a fix or solution for this, that I only get the value of it's own tag and not all their children as well?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can iterate over all **data* elements and take their values one by one using root.Elements("data") instead of Value.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned: I use a generated XML file, so I don't know that I need to select data. That was an example. I just need to get the value of the data tag (without knowing it is data). I do iterate through all items, that's why I use element.Value. But all the values of the children get added to that. I want a solution to that.

Comment: There's a difference between `XElement` and `XNode`. In simple terms, nodes > tags. Each element is a node but not every node is a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This obtains all of the text immediately within the element and none of its descendants' text:

```
var textValues = element.Nodes()
                        .Where(n => n.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
                        .Select(n => n.ToString().Trim());

string value = string.Join("", textValues); // value is:   This is a test value
```

Answer (score 0):

With xpath:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(/*The path to your xml*/);
XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("/data");

var v = node.FirstChild; //This contains "This is a test value"
```

Comment: Your fourth line is unnecessary. `root` would already be positioned at the `data` element and you can just use that. This does however assume that the desired text is the first child node of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq2Xml, try this:

```
string xmlString = //read your XML or load the file using XDocument.Load();
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
System.Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.FirstNode);
```

This works in every case, by replacing `doc.Root` with the targeted `XElement`.